# Only show specific groups in a df pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hel lo, I need to focus on specific group within a table.

Here is an exemple:

```
groups col1 
A 3
A 4
A 2
A 1
B 3
B 3
B 4
C 2
D 4
D 3
```

and I would like to only show groups that contain 3 and 4 but no other number. 
Here I should get :

```
groups col1 
B 3
B 3
B 4
D 4
D 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are possible 2 approaches - test values by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for membership and then get all groups with all `True`s by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html), last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['col1'].isin([3,4]).groupby(df['groups']).transform('all')]
print (df1)
  groups  col1
4      B     3
5      B     3
6      B     4
8      D     4
9      D     3
```

Another approach is first get all groups values, which `NOT` contains values `3,4` and pass to another `isin` function with inverted mask:

```
df1 = df[~df['groups'].isin(df.loc[~df['col1'].isin([3,4]), 'groups'])]
print (df1)
  groups  col1
4      B     3
5      B     3
6      B     4
8      D     4
9      D     3
```

Comment: Why are you performing the `groupby` instead of returning the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [`GroupBy.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
new_df=df.groupby('groups').filter(lambda x: x.col1.isin([3,4]).all() )
print(new_df)

  groups  col1
4      B     3
5      B     3
6      B     4
8      D     4
9      D     3
```

---

an alternative to remove `Series.isin` from the lambda function:

```
df['aux']=df['col1'].isin([3,4])
df.groupby('groups').filter(lambda x: x.aux.all()).drop('aux',axis=1)
```

Comment: I agree with you here it is slower because the lambda function is complex

Comment: yes, I also thought about that, I added a solution to remove Series.isin from the filter method. What I don't see is how to do it without creating that auxiliary column

Comment: hmmm, thinking and a but problem, also if used `s = df['col1'].isin([3,4])` cannot be used with `filter` :( Not idea, personally avoid this function for performance reasons...

Answer (score 0):

Using `df.loc[]` and then searching by normal logic should work.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['A', 3],
        ['A', 4],
        ['A', 2],
        ['A', 1],
        ['B', 3],
        ['B', 3],
        ['B', 4],
        ['C', 2],
        ['D', 4],
        ['D', 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["col1", "col2"])

df = df.loc[df["col2"] >= 3]
print(df.head())
```